# correlated variables from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, correlation

I am trying to develop a loop that will help allow me to dynamically control the correlation between two variables, while holding other variables correlations static.  I have this completed, but I cannot get the loop to perform a correlation among the variables for each level of the correlation.  In other words, the only correlation matrix I get is at the last level that I am specifying.  I would like to get a correlation matrix for each level using the cor function.  This way I can make sure R is performing my loop properly, and I can use the data in different statistical applications.  So I am clear, this is **NOT** a class project, but a real project.

Here is the code I am using to this point.

```
require("JWileymisc")
require("MASS")

cor.level <- c(0, .1, .2)
for (j in 1:length(cor.level)) {
  V <- matrix(c(
    1, cor.level[j], .096, .043, .109, 
    cor.level[j], 1, .400, -.016, .297, 
    .096, .400, 1, .092, .382, 
    .043, -.016, .092, 1, .103, 
    .109, .297, .382, .103, 1), 
    5, 5)
  sigma <- c(.4421, 1.0880, 8.5073, .4700, 1.1249)
  Sigma <- cor2cov(V, sigma)
  mu <- c(.7337, 2.7300, 46.9970, 2.6002, 1.7491)
  d <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=300, mu, Sigma, 5, 5))
  co <- cor(d)
  co
}
```

I am sure my error is very simple, but I am not seeing it at the moment.  Will someone help me achieve 3 correlation matrices one for each level of the cor.level specified above using the cor function?

Comment: do you need `empirical=TRUE` so that the correlations you get are *exactly* the specified values?

Comment: You are overwriting `co` on each iteration through the loop. Perhaps you need to save them in a list `co[[j]] <- cor(d)`

Comment: This is great, and it works!  Thank you Ben and Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loop.

```
library("JWileymisc"); library("MASS")
cor.level <- c(0, .1, .2)

co <- vector('list', length(cor.level))
for (j in 1:length(cor.level)) {
  V <- matrix(c(
    1, cor.level[j], .096, .043, .109, 
    cor.level[j], 1, .400, -.016, .297, 
    .096, .400, 1, .092, .382, 
    .043, -.016, .092, 1, .103, 
    .109, .297, .382, .103, 1), 
    5, 5)
  sigma <- c(.4421, 1.0880, 8.5073, .4700, 1.1249)
  Sigma <- cor2cov(V, sigma)
  mu <- c(.7337, 2.7300, 46.9970, 2.6002, 1.7491)
  co[[j]] <- cor(mvrnorm(n=300, mu, Sigma, 5, 5))
}
co
```

Better use `lapply` though.

```
library("JWileymisc"); library("MASS")
cor.level <- c(0, .1, .2)

lapply(cor.level, \(x) {
  V <- matrix(c(
    1, x, .096, .043, .109, 
    x, 1, .400, -.016, .297, 
    .096, .400, 1, .092, .382, 
    .043, -.016, .092, 1, .103, 
    .109, .297, .382, .103, 1), 
    5, 5)
  sigma <- c(.4421, 1.0880, 8.5073, .4700, 1.1249)
  Sigma <- cor2cov(V, sigma)
  mu <- c(.7337, 2.7300, 46.9970, 2.6002, 1.7491)
  m <- mvrnorm(n=300, mu, Sigma, 5, 5)
  cor(m)
})
```

Output of both:

```
[[1]]
              [,1]          [,2]  [,3]   [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  1.000000e+00 -6.645591e-16 0.096  0.043 0.109
[2,] -6.645591e-16  1.000000e+00 0.400 -0.016 0.297
[3,]  9.600000e-02  4.000000e-01 1.000  0.092 0.382
[4,]  4.300000e-02 -1.600000e-02 0.092  1.000 0.103
[5,]  1.090000e-01  2.970000e-01 0.382  0.103 1.000

[[2]]
      [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 1.000  0.100 0.096  0.043 0.109
[2,] 0.100  1.000 0.400 -0.016 0.297
[3,] 0.096  0.400 1.000  0.092 0.382
[4,] 0.043 -0.016 0.092  1.000 0.103
[5,] 0.109  0.297 0.382  0.103 1.000

[[3]]
      [,1]   [,2]  [,3]   [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 1.000  0.200 0.096  0.043 0.109
[2,] 0.200  1.000 0.400 -0.016 0.297
[3,] 0.096  0.400 1.000  0.092 0.382
[4,] 0.043 -0.016 0.092  1.000 0.103
[5,] 0.109  0.297 0.382  0.103 1.000
```

Comment: As I gain more experience, I will consider this method.  Thank you for the contribution Jay.